# how can I create mysql table with HTML and Nodejs

Tags: html, mysql, node.js

I want to represent a table on the nodejs server using mysql data.

I hope my nodejs will be used like the following html source code.

```
          <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Profile</th>
                <th>Update</th>
                <th>Delete</th>                      
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>egoing</td>
            <td>developer</td>
            <td>Update</td>
            <td>Delete</td>            
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>duru</td>
            <td>database admnistrato</td>
            <td>Update</td>
            <td>Delete</td>            
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>taeho</td>
            <td>developer</td>
            <td>Update</td>
            <td>Delete</td>

         </tr>
```

However, my source code inserts mysql data in horizontal order.

this is my source code..   (***author_information*** is object)

```
author_List:function(author_information) {
            var line = `
            <body>
                <table>
                <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Profile</th>
                <th>Update</th>
                <th>Delete</th>


         </tr>
            `

            var a_Name = `<tr>`;
            var a_Profile = `<tr>`;
            var a_Update = `<tr>`;
            var a_Delete = `<tr>`;

        for (var i = 0 ; i < author_information.length ; i++) {



            a_Name = a_Name + `<td>${author_information[i].name}</td>`;
            a_Profile = a_Profile + `<td>${author_information[i].profile}</td>`
            a_Update = a_Update + `<td><a href="/">Update</a></td>`;
            a_Delete = a_Delete + `<td><a href="/">Delete</a></td>`;

        }
        a_Name = a_Name + `</tr>`;
        a_Profile = a_Profile + `</tr>`;
        a_Update = a_Update + `</tr>`;
        a_Delete = a_Delete + `</tr>`;
        line = line + a_Name + a_Profile + a_Update + a_Delete + `</table></body>`
        return line;
    }
```

How can I put data vertically in a column?

Comment: The html you're building in your 2nd code snippet is a table with 4 rows total with all `<td>..</td>` of a specific category (name, profile, update, delete) concatenated, is that normal? If you want to get the same structure as the source code on top of your post, you should build a `<tr><td>name</td><td>profile</td><td>update</td><td>delete</td></tr>` for each iteration of your for-loop

Answer (score 0):

To expand on my comment, here is how you should create your html to achieve the same structure as the example you gave (I also removed the `a_...` variables, you don't really need them, and used `line += X` instead of `line = line + X`):

```
author_List:function(author_information) {
        var line = `
        <body>
            <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Profile</th>
                <th>Update</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>`;

    for (var i = 0 ; i < author_information.length ; i++) {

        line+= `<tr>`;
            line += `<td>${author_information[i].name}</td>`;
            line += `<td>${author_information[i].profile}</td>`
            line += `<td><a href="/">Update</a></td>`;
            line += `<td><a href="/">Delete</a></td>`;
        line+= `</tr>`;
    }

    line += `</table></body>`
    return line;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using arrays made it easy to write the code I wanted. Thank you for your answers.

```
author_List:function(author_information) {
            var line = `
            <body>
                <table>
             <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Profile</th>
                <th>Update</th>
                <th>Delete</th>                      
             </tr>
            `


           var number = new Array();
           for ( var a = 0 ; a <author_information.length ; a++){
            for (var i = 0 ; i < author_information.length ; i++){
                number[i] = `<tr><td>${author_information[i].name}</td><td>${author_information[i].profile}</td>
                            <td><a href="/">Update</a></td><td><a href="/">Delete</a></td></tr>`;                        
            }
            line = line + number[a];
           }
           linee = line + `</table></body>`
        return line;
    }
```